# browser.extension.getViews({type: "popup"}) is not working for edge extension

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

Can someone give me some alternative as to how to send a message to a view in edge . I just saw the page for extension.getViews() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getViews). It is incompatible with edge. So what should I use instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

You should view Edge extension api status here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis#extension. From this link, Microsoft Edge has already supported `browser.extension.getViews`.

Comment: Open this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getViews) . It is written there and you can check browser compatibility is not there for edge . I got this link from clicking your link and then clicking on extension.getViews . Please once check before you answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practise to use *getViews* api. You can use `runtime.sendmessage` & `runtime.onmeesage.addlistener` to communicate between two context(bg an popup for example). Otherwsie you can use *ports* to do long time communication